# IOS - UIPageControl creates space below statusbar

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

i have a question about the UIPageControl. I have a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl. When I add the UIPageControl in front of the UIScrollView I get a space below the status-bar. The backgroundColor is white that's why there is a white bar:

[image: Bug]

This is how it should look like:

[image: normal]

This is my structure:

[image: structure]

And my xib-file:

[image: xib]

When I add for example a button or a label on the same position (z-Index) like the paginator everything works. Only the paginator makes trouble. Can someone explain me what I'm missing here? Is there something special about the UIPageControl?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to remove the empty space. I just have to add the following line in the `viewDidLoad` of the related ViewController:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```